# Upload file to server through AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

So I have been trying and trying to convert my site from uploading statusupdates with and without images using only PHP and HTML to use PHP, AJAX and HTML so it doesn't have to make a whole new page load to successfully update the database and such and it went well til' I had to upload images along.

My JavaScript/jQuery/AJAX code looks like this:

```
$(function() {  
$("#statusupdate").on('submit', function (e) {  
    var category = $("#statusupdate input[type=radio]:checked").val();
var text = $("textarea#statusupdate_text").val();
var file = $("input#file").val();
$.ajax({  
type: "POST",  
url: "snippets/post_statusupdatequery.php",  
data: { category : category, text : text, file : file },  
success: function() {  
$('#statusupdate').html("<div id='success_status'></div>");  
$('#success_status').html("<h2>Post Submitted!</h2>")  
.append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>")  
.hide();  
}  
});
    return false;  
e.preventDefault();
});  
});
```

http://pastebin.com/fSGFa32D
and my PHP code looks like this:

```
if (!empty($_FILES['userfile'])) {
$raw_text = $_POST['text'];
$text = mysql_real_escape_string($raw_text);
$uploaddir = '/var/www/images/imageupdate/';
$filename = "".$id."-".$time."";
$uploadfilenam = basename($filename);
$uploadfilename = $uploadfilenam.".png";
$uploadfile = $uploaddir.$uploadfilename;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
mysql_query("INSERT INTO imagepost
    (userid, text, image, date)
    VALUES('$id', '$text', '$uploadfilename', '$time') ") or die(mysql_error());
             }
 } else {
    echo '<script>alert(" Select a file to upload! ");</script>';
  }
```

http://pastebin.com/6Yam6Mtd

Currently as far as I know, it fails on the first if statement in the PHP code and I have googled and searched all over stackoverflow but I can't find a problem similar to this one.

So please help, what have I missed to get files to get "sent through AJAX" to PHP?

Comment: Please paste your code here.

Answer (score 0):

you can't upload a file using this javascript syntax

```
var file = $("input#file").val();
```

use the jquery ajax [form](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) to submit forms with file elements in it. also ensure the form has a `enctype=multipart/form-data`

To get ajax form to work first you setup your html form

```
<form id="myform" ...>.........</form>
```

Then you can have the `jquery` code attached to the form submit event by simply doing

```
$('#myform').ajaxForm(); //you can pass the same options as you would pass to $.ajax();
```

Comment: The form do have the right enctype. But I doesn't really understand how the ajax form thing works even after looking at examples. At the moment after testing I currently only have the JS-code on the frontpage from the website you linked so when I click the submit button I get "Thank you for your comment!" but it doesn't upload anything or such, I am sorry but I don't quite understand how the ajax form work.

Comment: take a look at my updated answer

Comment: only two things I don't get right now 1. Where should I put $('#myform').ajaxForm();? In the submit (onclick) or just in a <script>-tag? 2. With options to $.ajax do you mean so i "basically" just change $.ajax to $('#myform').ajaxForm();?

Comment: if you want to rename your ajax to ajaxForm then rename it to ajaxSubmit

Comment: I mean't like the JS-code in the question I have written and then just replace the word "$.ajax" with "$('#myform').ajaxForm()" or does it not work like that?

Comment: use `ajaxSubmit()` if you are renaming the `$.ajax()`. use `$.ajaxForm()` if your declaring it outside of any event trigger